# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider not registered

Tags: visual-studio-2013, oledb, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to connect my access database using Visual Studio 2013 running on Windows 8.
I found some fixes but they don't work for me.

First, I tried installing [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) (AccessDatabaseEngine_x64) and installed it successfully but it is giving me the same error.

Another fix that I found was installing [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734) but running the file gives me the error "The installation of this package failed."

Im running Office Professional Plus 2013 64-bit, Windows 8 Pro 64-bit, and Visual Studio Professional 2013

Comment: How is your solution setup to build: 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: i tried using 32-bit and 64-bit and I still get the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same thing.  Try installing the Office2007 redist as well - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/23734 . Solved my prob.

Comment: This link is broken

Answer (score 0):

go to your project properties > compile > and uncheck the Prefer-32bit